# Сортировка людей по возрасту python

Tags: python

Стоит задача сделать сортировку людей по возрасту

От 0 до 12 - дети

От 12 до 18 - подростки

От 18 до 27 - клуб 27

От 27 до 45 - молодые

От 45 до 60 - зрелые

От 60 до 74 - пожилые

От 74 до 90 - молоды в душе

От 90 и выше -  долгожители

Я немного не понимаю как это всё верно сделать... Когда запускаю работает некорректно

Вот как делал я:

```
array = []

print("Введите ваш возраст")
age = input()
for i in age:
    if i == 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12:
        print("Вы занесены в группу - дети.")
    else:
        continue

for i in age:
    if i == 13 or 14 or 15 or 16 or 17 or 18:
        print("Вы занесены в группу - подростки.")
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: 1 or 2 or ... 99 а вы усидчивый ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print("Введите ваш возраст")

while True:
    age = input()
    if not age.isdigit():
        print("Введите целое число")
    else:
        age = int(age)
        break

if age <= 12:
    print("От 0 до 12 - дети")
elif age <= 18:
    print("От 12 до 18 - подростки")
elif age <= 27:
    print("От 18 до 27 - клуб 27")
elif age <= 45:
    print("От 27 до 45 - молодые")
elif age <= 60:
    print("От 45 до 60 - зрелые")
elif age <= 74:
    print("От 60 до 74 - пожилые")
elif age <= 90:
    print("От 74 до 90 - молоды в душе")
else:
    print("От 90 и выше - долгожители")
```

Comment: у вас лишние сравнения elif: `12 < age`, ...

Comment: и добавить бы = в условия, а то "переходные" возрасты попадут в else... и 12 < age and age < 18 легче воспринимается и короче записать как 12 < age <= 18

Comment: да, 18 попадает в долгожители.

Comment: @Jack_oS спасибо за комментарий, исправил

Comment: @АндрійПанчій, зачем 2 условия `elif 12 < age <= 18:`? Просто `age <= 18:`.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru спасибо за совет, исправил

Answer (score 3):

Приведенные ниже решения удобны если данные о возрастах получаются откуда-то с сервера или из файла если нет то можно использовать простую конструкцию `if/else` - это будет оптимальным решением.

Иначе можно использовать регулярки, плюс от такого подхода в том что данные находятся в одном месте изменяя строки не нужно дополнительно менять `if условие`

```
import re;

age = 27

ages = [
  "От 0 до 12 - дети",
  "От 12 до 18 - подростки",
  "От 18 до 27 - клуб 27",
  "От 27 до 45 - молодые",
  "От 45 до 60 - зрелые",
  "От 60 до 74 - пожилые",
  "От 74 до 90 - молоды в душе",
  "От 90 и выше - долгожители"
]
for i in ages: 
  [from_age, to_age] = [
    ''.join(j) # убираем пустые совпадения: ''
    for j      # выбираем все что относится к возрасту
    in re.findall(r'От (\d+)|до (\d+|)|и (выше)', i)
  ]
  if (to_age == 'выше' or age <= int(to_age)):
    s = i.split('-')[1] # получаем определение возраста
    print(f'Вы занесены в группу -{s}')
    break
```

Но регулярки могут быть не продуктивными, поэтому можно то же сделать словарями, код получится проще не нужен будет модуль `re`
и так же данные нигде не будут дублироваться:

```
age = 100
 
ages = [
  {'f': 0, 't': 12, 'n': 'дети'},
  {'f': 12, 't': 18,  'n': 'подростки'},
  {'f': 18, 't': 27,  'n': 'клуб 27'},
  {'f': 27, 't': 45,  'n': 'молодые'},
  {'f': 45, 't': 60,  'n': 'зрелые'},
  {'f': 60, 't': 74,  'n': 'пожилые'},
  {'f': 74, 't': 90,  'n': 'молоды в душе'},
  {'f': 90, 't': 'выше', 'n': 'долгожители'}
]

for i in ages: 
  from_age, to_age, group = i['f'], i['t'], i['n']
  if (to_age == 'выше' or age <= to_age):
    print(f'Вы занесены в группу - {group}')
    break
```

Можно заметить что `from_age` не используется поэтому его вообще можно исключить из данных если только не нужно формировать строку типа `от ... до ...` а так же вместо словаря использовать простой массив если данные как в данном случае не сложные.

Comment: а зачем конверсия `int`? Вместо `выше` можно использовать `float("inf")`. Либо проверять с конца.

Comment: я думаю числа лучше сравнивать как числа, да можно вместо 'выше' использовать инфинити

Comment: я имею ввиду ваш 2 пример, там можно int убрать, числа там не хранятся как текст.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru наверно все же первый пример, в словарях числа же как числа, а ну да там преобразование лишнее, спасибо уберу

Answer (score 1):

Можно перевернуть условия:

```py
if age >= 90:
    print("От 90 и выше - долгожители")
elif age >= 74:
    print("От 74 до 90 - молоды в душе")
elif age >= 60:
    print("От 60 до 74 - пожилые")
elif age >= 45:
    print("От 45 до 60 - зрелые")
elif age >= 27:
    print("От 27 до 45 - молодые")
elif age >= 18:
    print("От 18 до 27 - клуб 27")
elif age >= 12:
    print("От 12 до 18 - подростки")
else:
    print("От 0 до 12 - дети")
```